# WCF to consume web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Newbie here. Unsure of how to ask let alone use the proper terminology right. This is my first time working with servers, webservices, and WCF. I'm doing this all in VB.net.

I'm tasked to program a server that receive a sms response from the client. The client provides an asmx webservice(i think).

I have one server running, implemented with WCF, that I thought was properly set up and waiting till it received some sort of message but it never did.

I then started to do more research and found that WCF has some legacy code that can let you consume webservices (httpbinding i believe).

How would I implement this exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry but this really is too vague. You can't just write a WCF service and wait for it to receive messages. If you want to receive messages from a client's web service, you'll have to get its address and generate a client from the metadata. Then you can send messages to it, perhaps to request the sms messages it has received, but how it works should be described in a manual of some sort your client must be able to provide.

Comment: Like I said this is all a first for me. 
The client provides a WSDL(used the WSDL.exe from visual studios) that gives me all the metadata, ip address, function declarations, etc. I gave them the IP of my server so they can connect. 

Their documentation is pretty vague, no mention if its using a webservice or WCF.

Comment: I think you should try to send a message to the server and see whats going first. The wsdl provided to you is what is your world to work on from client.Try to call their services and see whats happening . If you come across an error . Post that error here and we will see from there. Honestly the description you wrote is getting me hardtime to figure out your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish at this time, but I will cover what I can to help guide you in figuring out what you are trying to accomplish.

## Calling a third party endpoint

If you are just trying to consume a third party web service then you can use svcutil (or the add service reference in visual studio) to generate your proxy classes to connect to the third party. WSDL.exe has been around since .NET framework 1.1 while svcutil.exe came out in .NET 3.5. The main difference between the two is that svcutil.exe has support for features that wsdl.exe cannot support (such as WS-RM).

If the end goal is just to use the third party service than either svcutil.exe or using the Add Service Reference option in visual studio will do everything you need it to do. The fact that it is using classes that were created as part of WCF is not important.

## Defining an endpoint for third parties to call

If a third party needs to send you data, and the data needs to be sent in real time (not batched) then WCF is one of the preferred solutions today in the if you are programming in a .NET language (you could also use ASMX service, create an http handler, etc). If this is the actual requirement then it is possible that the WSDL they provided is the specification of what they want the endpoint you create to look like (the contract that they want to consume). This is an example of the possible steps at that point:

1. Create the service contract based on that provided WSDL.
2. Create a class implementing the contract from step 1.
3. Deploy and test the service yourself with appropriate test data.
4. Test that you can use the endpoint from an external internet connection(1)(2)
5. Let the client know that they the endpoint is ready for them to test.

Hopefully this gives you a high level overview of what you should be thinking of and what your next steps will be.

(1)If it's a client that is internal to your organization than the test only needs to be from withing your internal network

(2)If the client is external to your organization you will need to research about WCF security. You do not want just anybody to be able to hit your endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into WCF security. Right now I can't even say for sure if my implementation of the WCF/Server are working since our client has yet to get back to us. I've tested the server using a TestClient i wrote up that would consume my WCF and that worked. Just a matter of waiting now :S

Comment: As an aside the reference that helped me out the most when I did my first WCF projects was the book Learning WCF by Michele Leroux Bustamante. The O'Reilly website has a part of the book available through a Google Preview button so you can see if it would be useful to you. Only potential negative is that I can't remember if they had VB.NET samples or not, but if you read the book you'll have an above average understanding of how WCF is structured, why it's structed the way it is, and how to best use it.

Answer (score 1):

As a noobie, it can really be difficult trying to understand how all the parts fit together. Your best bet is to run through a couple of WCF noobie tutorials. A quick google search for "developing your first wcf" gave some promising results:

[Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx)

[Creating and Consuming Your First WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service)

Good Luck