# how to resolve WCF service cycle call issue in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

My project is using asp.net+WCF

And there are several fucntional modules:

1.ASP module

2.WCFServiceModule

3.FunctionMudule

in the past,the call chain is ASP(added wcfServiceReference) ->FunctionModule(added wcfServiceReference)->WCFServiceModule functions ,it works well.

but current, i want run a background task written in FunctionModule.

So there is another new call chain: WCFServiceModule ->FunctionModule(added wcfServiceReference) -> WCFServiceModule functions

I am facing an issue:
for running this new call chain. should add wcf service reference itself in WCFServiceModule,

like this: WCFServiceModule(added wcfServiceReference) ->FunctionModule(added wcfServiceReference) -> WCFServiceModule functions

If not add self self reference, FunctionModule can't find WCFServiceModule services.

that's really a bad solution,

How to fix this issue?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you want wcf to call the tripartite module and return data to wcf? If this is the case, you can use svcutil or add a service reference. Refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820316/wcf-to-consume-web-service) for more details.

Comment: @Jiayao thanks for your reply. my problem is the FunctionModule already calls wcf with wcfserviceReference. so when wcf call FunctionModule . needs to add wcfservicereference on wcf itself. cyclic call happens.

Comment: If they are in the same project, you can try using channelfactory instead of service reference. However,  forgive me for not understanding the step of wcf calling function.